Choosing the Bound Order when Determining Area Bounded by Parametric Curve
This question is probably ill-defined, but it arose as I was reviewing material and struggled to grapple with it.
Suppose we have a parameterized curve with the following equations:
$$ x(t) = 2a\cos(t) - a\cos(2t)$$
$$ y(t) = 2a\sin(t) - a\sin(2t)$$
I was prompted to find the area bounded by this parametric curve from $ 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$. As such, I set up the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}y(t)x'(t)dt = -6\pi a^2$$
The solution key, however, claimed that the answer is $6\pi a^2$. The difference in these answers is a sign, leading to some confusion. I have attached the curve graph when $a=1$.

Namely, my integration reflects that the first section of the curve ($0 \leq t \leq \pi$) lies above the x-axis but is traced right to left, meaning that the area is technically negative. Likewise, the second portion of the curve ($\pi \leq t \leq 2\pi$) lies below the x-axis and is traced left to right, meaning the area is technically negative. In total, then, the area should be negative.
But other issues quickly emerged. Moreover, recall that the question asks to find the "area bounded by the parametric curve from $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$." I imposed a direction on this integration by setting my lower bound to be $0$ and my upper bound to be $2\pi$. Yet, is this direction not arbitrary? Nowhere does it seem necessary to say that the integration must proceed in this direction.
In this way, one could see my answer as the integration in which the bounds were ascending, whereas the textbook's answer is the integration in which the bounds were descending. What makes one of these choices "correct" and the other "incorrect"? Or is the question just poorly worded? That is, the prompt should ask for the magnitude of the area, not the "area"––which is an ambiguous term given my discussion above.

This will be a long answer. The first part is a general discussion of area problems to set up the context in which to address your particular problem. But it all comes down in the end to inferring the purpose of a problem statement and using the right formula for the right purpose.

As you probably know, there are two ways to travel along the boundary of a region: clockwise or counterclockwise. Clockwise means the interior of the region is on the right-hand side of the curve; counterclockwise means the interior is on the left.
There is a way of accounting for the area enclosed by a curve in which areas enclosed by a counterclockwise loop have positive area and areas enclosed by a clockwise loop have negative area.
Another way area can have a sign is when we talk about the "area under a curve" in a Cartesian plane. Area between the curve and the $x$-axis is counted as positive for parts of the curve above the $x$-axis and negative for parts of the curve below the $x$-axis.
There are a few semantic concerns here. For one thing, if we simply say "area" without further qualification, do we mean the kind of measurement of area described in the previous paragraphs, or do we mean the kind of area in which a collection of points in the plane has zero area or positive area, that is, area has only magnitude, not a positive or negative "direction"? And if the area has a sign, is the sign determined by the orientation of the boundary, is it determined by which side of the $x$-axis it's on, or is there some other way of deciding whether a region has positive or negative area?
Within a chapter of a textbook there will be clues as to which kind of area we want.
A big clue is the words "area under the curve," which tell us to use a particular type of signed area but also signals that the curve needs to pass the vertical line test.
When such curves are described parametrically, it's because it's too hard to write $y$ as a function of $x$ explicitly, even though we know the function exists.
An example is the area under one arch of a cycloid sitting on the $x$-axis, which I kept finding over and over in a web search for area defined by parameterized curves.
In order that the area under the graph of a function be positive above the $x$-axis, we integrate the function from left to right. We also integrate left to right when the graph of the function is parameterized. In Paul's Online Notes there are two formulas given for the area under a parametric curve: one in which the parameterization starts at the left end of the curve, and one in which it starts at the right end. The difference between the two formulas is that we choose the starting and ending values of the parameter $t$ so that the curve is traced from left to right. If $\mathrm dx\mathrm dt < 0,$ we integrate $t$ from its maximum value to its minimum value.
The formula
$$ \int_\alpha^\beta y(t) x'(t)\,\mathrm dt \tag1$$
is frequently given as a formula for area under a parameterized curve where the curve is the graph of a function, and it gives the desired answer only if the integral is set up so that $x(\alpha)$ is the left end of the curve and $x(\beta)$ is the right end.The
Another area formula is
$$ \frac12 \int_\alpha^\beta (-y(t) x'(t) + x(t) y'(t))\,\mathrm dt. \tag2$$
This is sometimes written as
$$ \frac12 \int_C (-y \,\mathrm dx + x \,\mathrm dy). $$
This is the formula for the signed area inside a curve where area enclosed by a counterclockwise loop is positive.
The formula ($2$) differs from the "area under the parameterized curve" formula ($1$) in two ways.
One way ($2$) differs from ($1$) is that it has both a $y(t)x'(t)$ term and an $x(t)y'(t)$ term.
A second way it differs is that it has the opposite sign for the $y(t)x'(t)$ term.
The opposite sign is due to the fact that when we trace a curve from left to right to measure the area under it, as ($1$) is designed to do, positive area is on the right side of the curve and negative area is on the left, but the area measured by ($2$) is supposed to be positive on the left side of the curve and negative on the right.
If you consider a simple region bounded by the $x$-axis below and by the graph of a function of $x$ above, and we use formula ($1$) to measure the area of the region by tracing the function's curve parametrically from left to right, we are tracing part of the boundary of the region in a clockwise sense (the interior is on the right side of the curve). That's another way of seeing why the sign of the $y(t)x'(t)$ term must be opposite in the two formulas; if we used the same sign as in ($2$), the clockwise boundary would necessarily give us negative area.
The two terms are a byproduct of the derivation of the formula. Their integrals turn out to be equal in magnitude in many cases. (I say "many" in case there are exceptions, although I don't know any.) In fact, if the region is bounded by a simple curve, the integral of each term individually has the same magnitude as the entire region, which is why we multiply everything by $\frac12$.

Now let's consider your particular problem. "Area under the curve" does not appear to be a good interpretation; first of all, the curve is not the graph of a function, and second, if we divide the curve into pieces that are graphs of functions, the total area under all these curves is zero, because the portion below the $x$-axis is symmetric to the portion above and cancels it completely.
This alone is a good reason not to use the "area under a curve" formula.
If we are using the definition of area enclosed by a curve where a counterclockwise boundary gives positive area, and we consider the positive $t$ direction to be the orientation of the boundary, the area should be positive. If we're using the definition of area that says any collection of points with a measurable area has a non-negative area, then the area must be positive.
So we should either use something like formula ($2$), or we should adapt formula ($1$) to give a positive area as required by the problem.
Either way, the sign of the answer yielded by formula ($1$) must be reversed,
because the unmodified formula ($1$) is designed to measure a positive area when the orientation of the boundary is clockwise.
